# How to model anomaly data using Gaussian distribution assuming variables are dependent? (In Python)

Tags: python, anomaly-detection, gaussian

I have some data which contains **anomalies** as well.

I want to model data using **Gaussian distribution** assuming **variables** are **dependent** in **Python**.

How can I model this? Should I use the PDF formula as a function, figure out the probabilities and take out the accuracy?

**Note:** This has been given as an assignment in my college. I am trying to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume variables are dependent, in a Gaussian distribution this means the covariance matrix is not diagonal.

Answer (score -1):

You can start with considering the multi-dimensional Gaussian distribution. Its density is
$$ f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n|\Sigma|}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x - \mu)\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\right)$$
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Non-degenerate_case)

I suggest using the maximum likelihood approach to tune the parameters or any anomaly detection algorithm you know.